# ASP User Control Event Fires After Containing Page's OnLoadComplete

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I have a user control "UserApplianceControl" that I need to dynamically add to a asp page.

I am doing so with the following code:

User.aspx.cs

```
protected override void OnLoadComplete(EventArgs e)
    {

        base.OnLoadComplete(e);
        A5Lib.User u;
        UserServiceReference.UserServicesClient myProxy = new UserServiceReference.UserServicesClient();
        u = myProxy.GetUser("user1");

        if (listOfAppliances != null)
        {

            foreach (A5Lib.Appliance str in u.Appliances)
            {
                UserApplianceControl uac = (UserApplianceControl)LoadControl("UserApplianceControl.ascx");
                uac.setAppliance(str);
                Panel1.Controls.Add(uac);
            }
        }
    }
```

In UserApplianceControl, I have several buttons. However, whenever I press a button, the user control's button handler is never called. In fact OnLoadComplete(above) gets called first, and so those controls populated on the last page load are recreated and I lose the old ones before I can handle the event.

Why isn't the event firing before OnLoadComplete?

Comment: I'd bet my left shoe that something is happening on Page_Load on the parent page that's erasing the Button_Click event handler. How familiar are you with the Page Lifecycle?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx  90% of the time when this type of issue comes up it's because the developer isn't taking the Page Lifecycle into account, or is mistaken about the order of events firing.  I could be wrong, of course, but that'd be the first place I'd look.

Comment: I am not doing anything in Page_Load...ie its empty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are recreating your controls too late in the page lifecyle.

A dynamically added control must be present (loaded) no later than onInit for any viewstate/postback functionality to work.

Move your code to the page's OnInit event. This will ensure that all the controls are rebuilt BEFORE viewstate is restored and the page does all it's button/event hooking up.